# How to get the selected row from table model?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, indexoutofboundsexception

How to get the selected row from table model?
 I tried the following....

```
checkBoxes[t].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent  e) {

    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkBoxes[i] == e.getSource()) {

        String Status=null ;
        DbUtility ViewAbsenties=new DbUtility();
        ViewAbsenties.loadDriver();
        ViewAbsenties.connect();

        TableModel tm;
        tm = table3.getModel();

        if (checkBoxes[i].isSelected() == true) {
          Status  =(String) tm.getValueAt(i,8);
          System.out.println("Status : " + Status );

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when i run the above code, iam getting the following error.

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
    at EmployeeLeave$10$1.actionPerformed(EmployeeLeave.java:490)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: Your error suggests that the row you tried to access doesn't exist

Comment: Does your table have at least 9 columns? Have you tried to log which row you think the object is in and verify that against your interpretation of the model?

Comment: This question is about something different (selection is of checkboxes, not the table selection, and seeking value rather than index) but some people looking at the title might be hoping to find this: [getting selected row through AbstractTableModel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/856888/411282)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. there are three potential issues

   - [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)s view could be [Sorted or Filtered](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) then you have to [convertRowIndexToModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)
   - Array(s) started with zero (`getValue(0, 0`) is `1st. row` from `1st. column`)
   - have to set [javax.swing.ListSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) properly or determine all selected rows
2. for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)